# primefaces auto complete on focus show suggestions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Right now I have a situation like before we calculate the suggestions before the auto-complete text box gets the focus. So when the client places the cursor it has to display the suggestions so we can avoid client to type something.

I have tried `minQueryLength="0"` but no luck.

Here is the code snippet.

```
p:autoComplete value="#{x.selectedItems}"  multiple="true" dropdown="true" var="item"
   itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.label}" forceSelection="true"                                             minQueryLength="0" completeMethod="#{x.completeMethod}" converter="converter"
```

Comment: and your question is ...

Comment: You can start out with `onfocus="PF('widgetVarOfAutocomplete').search('')"` but it has some side effects

Answer (score 2):

We used:

```
onfocus="PF('widgetVarOfAutocomplete').search('')"
```

As Jaqen sugested, then treated on backing bean to find all results instead of just the matched.

Comment: And don't forget to add the `widgetVar` to the autoComplete

Answer (score 0):

To improve usability you might want to select the contents of the input field, so:

```
onfocus="PF('acVar').search('');PF('acVar').input.select()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method show() of autocomplete like, not forgetting to stopPropagation is very important because there is listener on body click event which hides dropdown:

```
<p:autoComplete click="magic($event)></p:autoComplete>

magic(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.autocomplete.show();
}
```